# WebMatrix ASP.NET Web Pages vs ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, webmatrix, asp.net-webpages

I've looked at WebMatrix 2 and it seems simple and fun to play with.

I play mainly with ASP.NET MVC 3 in C# with VS2010 Premium.

I'd like to know what's the pros and cons of using ASP.NET Web Pages, against using ASP.NET MVC 3.

And I'd like to know what's the pros and cons of WebMatrix too.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Web Pages is a much lighter-weight development model than MVC. You would use it when testability and code separation is not needed - proof of concept stuff perhaps, or just a relatively simple site.

Web Pages uses the Web Site model as opposed to the Web Application model. No precompilation. WebMatrix only supports that model so it's not much use for MVC, but for Web Pages sites, it opens up in a fraction of the time that it takes for Visual Studio to wake from its slumber.

Comment: I'm the PM for Web Pages and Razor. What Mike said is good guidance. If WebMatrix/Web Pages does everything you need I'd highly recommend using it. If not, then MVC and VS are the way to go.

There are obviously less features in WebMatrix vs. VS, but it just depends if you need them or not.

There are no limitations in Web Pages vs. MVC. It's simply a choice of programming model you'd like to use (single page model vs. MVC pattern), otherwise, all of ASP.NET is underneath both of them and they both use the Razor syntax.

Hope our answers help.

Comment: @ErikPorter Do you think that the Webpage Model fits better to the now  popular Single Page Application Model (Knockout, Backbone,...)?

Comment: @rudimenter I think it's a great option that I would personally use, but you'll more than likely be using Web API when building SPAs (though if you're just doing some simple data query and want to return some JSON and don't care about anything else, Web Pages is super simple for that!) and VS/MVC will have better support for that model out of the box than WebMatrix/Web Pages (at least right now). In fact, there is a SPA template in VS that uses MVC and Web API and is a sample app. P.S. I don't work at Microsoft anymore. :)