# From Classic ASP to WebMatrix or .NET MVC I'm confused?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I was doing some tutorials with ASP.Net MVC 5 in VS Express 2013 for Web, and overwhelmed by the learning curve of this MVC structure, and how it would apply in a similar case in Classic ASP development which I'm highly accustom to.  Now I just looked at WebMatrix and I'm completely confused now. I've realized WebMatrix Razor "Web Pages" are just like classic asp on steroids, and the learning curve appears to be 10x less than MVC 5, but I'm still confused.

I've noticed that MVC 5 has more components than Razor -- Controllers (.cs files) and Models (more .cs files), whereas WebMatrix Razor has only what appears to be Views (.cshtml files).

So It appears WM Razor is about a third of MVC 5.  Which is better news for me as being a classic asp developer -- Less learning curve.  But, am I missing out anything worth-while here by not using MVC 5?  Or are these technologies supposed to work together -- MVC 5 + WebMatrix Razor?  I'm really confused.  MVC 5 wants you to avoid putting code like DB conn, etc. in the view, whereas WM Razor isn't.  Are these two completely different frameworks? How am I supposed to know what's better for me now?  I was just doing classic asp 2 days ago, MVC 5 last night, and now WebMatrix, and I'm lost.

All I really want to do is to understand how to structure my existing classic asp site in either MVC 5 or WebMatrix Razor, but I don't want to do it and find out I should've done the other later.  If anyone who understands where I stand right now and give any insight on what to do I would appreciate it.

Comment: It's funny that the mod's want this topic closed, when it's a completely legitimate concern as it's been for a while.  Is it because they don't want to help? There needs to be a better website than stackoverflow if the mod's want to close questions like this.

Comment: See for example [WebMatrix ASP.NET Web Pages vs ASP.NET MVC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8157394/webmatrix-asp-net-web-pages-vs-asp-net-mvc-3). Web Pages, which can be built using WebMatrix, are all the beauty of Razor without MVC. If you want to build anything that resembles an actual application as opposed to a few web pages, use MVC. Anyway this is offtopic for SO. SO is for actual programming problems, you have an architecture problem. Try http://programmers.stackexchange.com or try reading some more. What both models do (Web Pages vs MVC) is explained on various places on the web.

Comment: Please note: Classic ASP refers to the original VB script based ASP, prior to ASP.NET.  What you are referring to is Classic ASP.NET (asp.net without WebForms)

Comment: The WebPages framework is not designed to be used in large applications and does not lend itself to good structure, proper design principles, or good separation of concerns.  ASP.NET MVC is more about building maintainable applications, while WebPages is more about cranking out individual pages.

Answer (score 2):

The confusion likely lies in the fact that there are a few newer Microsoft technologies that are designed to work together like building blocks whereas the Classic ASP.NET was an all-in-one package.

**Microsoft Syntax Choices:**

- **Classic ASP.NET Syntax**: The original <% %> syntax you are familiar with and common in Microsoft projects for over a decade.
- **Razor:** is the name for the new syntax that is more like JavaScript and uses *@var* rather than *<%="var" %>*. It is optional
  but recommended (as it is much less typing). If you look into ASP.Net
  MVC 1 or 2, you'll see the classic ASP.NET syntax was used instead.

*Either of these syntaxes go with any of the following. (although typically one is favored over another)*

**Microsoft Frameworks:**

- **Classic ASP.NET**: Simple page with HTML and classic ASP.NET syntax using VB or C# on the same page.
- **ASP.NET Web Forms**: Similar to the look of Classic ASP.NET, but mimics the Windows Forms event driven programming experience.
- **Webmatrix CSHTML** is intended for smaller projects and to appeal to classic ASP.NET programmers. It is much like a classic ASP.NET page with
  mixed HTML and C# programming on one page, but using Razor syntax
  and instead of the ASP.NET syntax. It allows for newer features than
  classic ASP.NET.
- **ASP.NET MVC:** Model View Controller is Microsoft's implementation of the MVC pattern that is used in many programming languages and is
  popular for web programming outside the Microsoft realm. It is
  intended for larger projects that benefit from a more file
  organization and for programmers familiar with the MVC pattern.
  *Using Razor with MVC is OPTIONAL, but common.*

It sounds to me that your best bet would be to use Webmatrix CSHTML and learn Razor well. Once you're comfortable with that, you may venture into MVC if your projects are large enough to need it. *(I would be happy to suggest how to restructure Webmatrix to MVC, but that would fit better in a different question.)*

It may also help researching the MVC pattern in general, not the Microsoft specific flavor to learn what types of issues it is designed to solve.

*Full disclosure:* my preference is Razor and MVC but I came from a non-Microsoft background and was already familiar with the MVC pattern.